# How can the Windows animations be accessed or extracted?

Tags: windows, winforms, animation

In terms of animation, I actually mean things like the file transfer avi used in Windows dialog boxes:

[image: File transfer animation]

I'm trying to find out first if there is a way to access these files, if not how to use them inside windows forms. I know about SysAnimate32 and how it works to provide animations in windows forms.

**How as users can we access or extract these from Windows?**

Comment: They are not "files", this art-work is embedded as a resource in one of the Windows executables.  If you know the particular executable file and the resource ID then you can dig it out, but Microsoft makes no guarantee that they won't change this.  In particular, this flying folder animation has been long retired.  You'll have to bring your own art-work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ResourcesExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) tool to extract resources from Windows executables or library files.

It can extract:

- icons
- bitmaps
- animated icons
- **AVI files**
- cursors
- other kinds of resources

and supports following file formats:

- `*.dll`
- `*.ocx`
- `*.exe`

---

### The test

Because of your comment, stating that it doesn't work, I've downloaded the [64-bit version](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resourcesextract-x64.zip) of the tool (because I'm using 64-bit version of Windows 7) and tested it on `.exe` and `.dll` files, which I've found in `C:\Windows\System32` folder.

1. I've run the tool with normal permissions, e.g. **not using** `Run as Administrator`

   - As source I chose every `.exe` file beginning with letter `P`
   - As destination I chose a new, empty folder
   - Picked `icons`, `animated icons` and `avi files` to extract

[image: Stage 1]

2. As a result I've successfully extracted **29 icons**

[image: Stage 2]

3. Because you said it didn't work on `.dll` files, I've decided to check them as well, using same method as in (1.)

[image: Stage 3]

4. As you can see it also successfuly extracted files, including animated `.avi` file

[image: Stage 4]

Here's mentioned `.avi` animation - it happens to be the bar for loading action:

[image: Loading animation]

---

As you can see it actually works, maybe you've simply downloaded wrong version?

Comment: One slight problem is that for me, the program does not work. No files are extracted. I have tried windows applications, .net applications and windows dlls and .net dlls. I have also tried Scan Subfolders and finally, Run as Administrator showed no progress.

Comment: @EpicMinecartz I've edited my answer, to prove that the tool works. Try to recreate my steps, and if it doesn't work, I'll have to know more about your system, version of ResourcesExtract and how exactly are you trying to use it, in order to help you.

Comment: Yep. That got it. I managed to get a version that would always give access denied, your link to the 64 bit works exactly perfect, plus I did find the avi files that I was looking for. Thanks!